# Polymer setting property Javascript error

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm very (very) new to Polymer, and I'm trying to create my first component.
I created a Plunker, but it's not working for some reason: http://plnkr.co/edit/RbcBuO9y8SUHyKqe7OJA

anyway, you can see my code on there.

It has a component blob-component.html, which is very basic. It just has a label and the content of the tag.

On the index.html, I want to update both of these when I click a button.

In the Plunker, the component isn't resolving the component, so we only get the innerHTML displaying, but when I run this in my development environment, I do get the label showing (twice, as defined).

However, when I try to set it on the click of the button, I get an error:

Unhandled exception in http://localhost:50169/Content/WebComponents/Polymer/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js
0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

This is occurring at

```
unsafeUnwrap(this).data = value;
```

If I put a breakpoint in, then I can see that

*this* is a defined object and

*e* = "Updated label Initial label"

As you can see, I've also tried using setAttribute() instead of just assigning the value, but I get the same issue.

This is obviously super simple, but I can't understand why it's happening.

This is in IE11. In Chrome, I don't get an error, but the label disappears when I click the button.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this example can help: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8XoJy?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, but I'm trying to update the values of the component from the container page. I guess the equivalent would be setting the "min" property of the my-parrent component from index.html?

Comment: I don't have IE, but a I refactored your example a bit, which may help: http://plnkr.co/edit/g8VgTMmlPTVzRXnderpE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your example. I'm trying this is Chrome but should fix other browsers too.

First and foremost you should notice that you polymer.html imports fails because CORS. In plunker, jsbin, etc you can use [polygit](http://polygit.org)

```
http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html
```

Second problem occurs when you change the `innerHTML`. When using [Shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/shadydom), which is the default, by setting the `innerHTML` property you simply remove any content that you declared inside you `<dom-module>`. In Chrome you can fix this by forcing Shadow DOM, but it will still not work as expected in Firefox/IE/Safari.

For now you should avoid replacing inner HTML completely and either work with the DOM node-by-node or wrap you tags content with an additional container:

```
<blob-component id="p">
  <div>
    Flip
  </div>
</blob-component>

<script>
   function changeLabels() {
     var blob = document.getElementById("p");
     blob.querySelector('div').innerHTML = "Flop";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, man, I thought I was being smart checking to see if I could change the content! That fixed it, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Well you know, it generally should work. But then, Shady DOM :(